# HTTP Status 500 - PHP FastCGI instance failed

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I've added JavaBridge to apache-tomcat/webapps/.
When I try to open JavaBridge in browser (`localhost:8080/JavaBridge`) I get

```
HTTP Status 500 - PHP FastCGI instance failed.
```

And without it I presume c/p JavaBridge.jar, php-script.jar and php-servlet.jar, and creating a test.php is useless.
How do i fix this problem?

I'm using *tomcat v7* on *JasperReports Server 6.0.1*

The rest of the error:

```
type Exception report

message PHP FastCGI instance failed.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: PHP FastCGI instance failed.
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:448)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)


root cause 

php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionException
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIInputStream.read(FCGIInputStream.java:58)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:362)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:433)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)


root cause 

java.io.IOException: Protocol error
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIInputStream.doRead(FCGIInputStream.java:67)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIInputStream.read(FCGIInputStream.java:54)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:362)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:433)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy files from `C:/PHP` to `C:/Program Files/PHP`

JavaBridge.war has incorrect php-cgi binary, and uses php.ini from
cgi directory. It must be installed in `C:/Program Files/PHP` *(C:/PHP does not work, unless somehow init-parmas are changed in web.xml)*

Check this 2 issues too.

1) Windows installation requires php.ini to be in `C:\WINDOWS`, unless you use
the following registry key to put it somewhere else:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\IniFilePath`.

2) Just for completeness, not a JavaBridge issue:  Don't use PHP installer
for Windows, doesn't provide everything.  Instead get the binary
distribution and unzip manually into `C:/Program Files/PHP`, add `C:/Program Files/PHP` into Windows Path, add `PHPRC=C:/Program Files/PHP env var`.  Modify
`php.ini` to change `extensions_dir=C:/Program Files/PHP/ext`

Comment: I added 2 issues please check them maybe it will help.

Comment: i did the 2 issues above, now i get   

HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

Comment: I do not know so much I am sorry